# Duplicate class in two offcial android libs, gradle fails

Tags: android, annotations, android-gradle-plugin, render, libs

I'm using a library that requires activate render script support mode. Like this

```
defaultConfig {

 minSdkVersion 14
 targetSdkVersion 23
 renderscriptTargetApi 20
 renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
```

But when I try to run the app, I have this:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation 
/Keep.class
```

Keep.class is in annotation-support lib and in `rendserscript` lib too, both from Google, so I don't know what to do exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred in latest(23) SDK version only. Can you try to change the build version to 22 or 21, change the dependencies also.

**For example**

```
android {
       compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
}
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'  
}
```

Comment: Until Google fix it, it seems the only option. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way to go about it now.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following modifications to my build.gradle file, and it is now working:

`renderScriptTargetApi 23`

and added

`configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' }`

I believe it's the second line that did the trick.

Comment: I know that probably work, excluding the lib, but I can't lost support-annotations. Thanks anyway.